# Can't get 74LS590 to work

Tags: counter

I'm currently trying to count the pulses from a 555 timer. I've opted to use a 74LS590 (8-bit binary counter with output register; 3-state).

However, I can't get the counter to count anything. I've checked on the datasheet and I think I wired everything right. Am I missing something ?

Thank you.

[image: Wiring of the 74LS590: pins 16, 13 and 10 tied high, pins 14, 12 and 8 tied low, clock pulse on pin 11, output on other pins]

Comment: A schematic, for a start.

Comment: To clarify that, just in case: A picture of a breadboard is not a schematic.

Comment: I'll know it for the next time, thank you for the information.

Comment: i just have to give you an upvote for the effort that you made to provide a clearest possible picture of your circuit ... even though it is not a schematic diagram, it is a pleasure to look at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wire pin 13 to pin 11 instead of VCC that will clock the count through output register. The output will be 1 count behind what is in the counter.

Comment: Thank you very much !